# 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')' when using 'useHistory' hook of 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the "useHistory" hook from 'react-router-dom' and I come across the error, '*TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')*'. Below is my code.

```
import './App.css';
import { React, useState } from 'react'
import Header from './Header';
import Register from './Register';
import Login from './Login';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  const [ loggedIn, setLoggedIn ] = useState(false)
  const history = useHistory()

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          {loggedIn ? <h1>Logged In</h1> : <Register setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} />}
        </Route>
        <Route path='/log-in'>
          {loggedIn ? () => history.push('/') : <Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} loggedIn={loggedIn} />}
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Why is 'history.push' causing this error within my ternary operator?

Comment: Try to define `BrowserRouter` in your parent component. **index**

Answer (score 0):

```
import { React, useState } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './login';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/log-in'>
         <Login/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

const Login=()=>{
  const history=useHistory()
  const [loggedin,setloggedin]=useState(true)
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!loggedin){
      history.push("/")
    }
  },[loggedin])
  return(
    <div>login</div>
  )
}
export default Login
```

In your code, the code inside your route  only will be executed that is

```
{loggedIn ? () => history.push('/') : <Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} loggedIn={loggedIn} />}
```

In which the code inside your app component will not be executed.
You can try the above code.